# How to get SharePoint SPListItem field value using Java?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

How to get a field 'value' of an SPListItem in Java?

I have managed to query the item in the list I wanted, here my code with CAML:

```
var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
query.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>Main</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>");
this.groupItems = list.getItems(query);
```

Now I have the item, what's next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared answer:

First:

```
//get context
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
//open web
var web = context.get_web();
//get list
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('yourListName');

var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
query.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>Value</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>");
//query to get item 
this.groupItems = list.getItems(query);

context.load(this.groupItems);
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.xmlSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.xmlFailure));
```

xmlSuccess and xmlFailure are the function to handle the execution query, if success, go to xmlSuccess function, else, go to xmlFailure.

Next:

```
//function xmlSuccess
var storeAll;
var listItemEnumerator = this.groupItems.getEnumerator();
while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext())
{
    var myList = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    storeAll = (myList.get_item('yourFieldName'));
}
```

Finally:

```
//loop your items you get
for(idx in storeAll)
{
    //do your code here with the items
}
```

Hope this help someone.